# camera extrinsic calibration

Tags: computer-vision, camera-calibration, extrinsic-parameters

I have a fisheye camera, which I have already calibrated. I need to calculate the camera pose w.r.t a checkerboard just by using a single image of said checkerboard,the intrinsic parameters, and the size of the squares of the checkerboards. Unfortunately many calibration libraries first calculate the extrinsic parameters from a set of images and then the intrinsic parameters, which is essentially the "inverse" procedure of what I want. Of course I can just put my checkerboard image inside the set of other images I used for the calibration and run the calib procedure again, but it's very tedious, and moreover, I can't use a checkerboard of different size from the ones used for the instrinsic calibration. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

EDIT: After reading francesco's answer, I realized that I didn't explain what I mean by calibrating the camera. My problem begins with the fact that I don't have the classic intrinsic parameters matrix (so I can't actually use the method Francesco described).In fact I calibrated the fisheye camera with the Scaramuzza's procedure (https://sites.google.com/site/scarabotix/ocamcalib-toolbox), which basically finds a polynom which maps 3d world points into pixel coordinates( or, alternatively, the polynom which backprojects pixels to the unit sphere). Now, I think these information are enough to find the camera pose w.r.t. a chessboard, but I'm not sure exactly how to proceed.

Comment: Let's say you have the two rays passing through the delimiting points of a side of a square `r1 = (x1,y1,1)` and `r2 = (x2,y2,1)` in normalized coordinates. Knowing that in world coordinates the rays are connected by a segment of length `w` (the width of the square) forming a triangle and that the coordinates of the point in world coordinates will be a multiple of the normalized ones, can you recover the pose by using these constraints on multiple points in a system maybe? Just an idea

Comment: yes, that is one of the ideas I have: basically I have to find the particular plane on which, by projecting all the checkerboard corners from the image, I get the original checkerboard with the correct square size and  perpendicular sides. So it's like I have a parametric plane and I need to find its parameters, and thus the pose.  But I'm not sure how to mathematically formalize the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the [solvePnP](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=pnp#bool%20solvePnP(InputArray%20objectPoints,%20InputArray%20imagePoints,%20InputArray%20cameraMatrix,%20InputArray%20distCoeffs,%20OutputArray%20rvec,%20OutputArray%20tvec,%20bool%20useExtrinsicGuess,%20int%20flags)) procedure calculates extrinsic pose for Chess Board (CB) in camera coordinates. openCV added a fishEye library to its 3D reconstruction module to accommodate significant distortions in cameras with a large field of view. Of course, if your intrinsic matrix or transformation is not a classical intrinsic matrix you have to modify PnP:

1. Undo whatever back projection you did
2. Now you have so-called normalized camera where intrinsic matrix effect was eliminated.

   k*[u,v,1]<sup>T</sup> = R|T * [x, y, z, 1]<sup>T</sup>

The way to solve this is to write the expression for k first:

```
k=R20*x+R21*y+R22*z+Tz
```

then use the above expression in

```
k*u = R00*x+R01*y+R02*z+Tx
k*v = R10*x+R11*y+R12*z+Tx
```

you can rearrange the terms to get Ax=0, subject to |x|=1, where unknown

x=[R<sub>00</sub>, R<sub>01</sub>, R<sub>02</sub>, T<sub>x</sub>, R<sub>10</sub>, R<sub>11</sub>, R<sub>12</sub>, T<sub>y</sub>, R<sub>20</sub>, R2<sub>1</sub>, R<sub>22</sub>, T<sub>z</sub>]<sup>T</sup>

and A, b
are composed of known u, v, x, y, z - pixel and CB corner coordinates;

Then you solve for x=last column of V, where A=ULV<sup>T</sup>, and assemble rotation and translation matrices from x. Then there are few ‘messy’ steps that are actually very typical for this kind of processing:

A. Ensure that you got a real rotation matrix - perform orthogonal Procrustes on your R2 = UV<sup>T</sup>, where R=ULV<sup>T</sup>

B. Calculate scale factor scl=sum(R2(i,j)/R(i,j))/9;

C. Update translation vector T2=scl*T and check for Tz>0; if it is negative invert T and negate R;

Now, R2, T2 give you a good starting point for non linear algorithm optimization such as Levenberg Marquardt. It is required because a previous linear step optimizes only an algebraic error of parameters while non-linear one optimizes a correct metrics such as squared error in pixel distances. However, if you don’t want to follow all these steps you can take advantage of the [fish-eye library](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=fisheye%20calibrate#double%20fisheye::calibrate(InputArrayOfArrays%20objectPoints,%20InputArrayOfArrays%20imagePoints,%20const%20Size&%20image_size,%20InputOutputArray%20K,%20InputOutputArray%20D,%20OutputArrayOfArrays%20rvecs,%20OutputArrayOfArrays%20tvecs,%20int%20flags%20,%20TermCriteria%20criteria)) of openCV.

Comment: I think the 3D points are just the corners of the "real"checkerboard, with the Z components all equal to zero. I actually tried to do what you Vlad have described, in fact I read the paper on which the calibration toolbox is based on and came up with a system of homogeneous equations (so there's no "b" vector as all the constant terms are zero). Unfortunately, trying to solve it with Matlab result in a trivial solution (null vector). Not sure what's wrong here.

Comment: aledalgrande, is you know chess board (CB) square size (say sz) you just put a local coordinate system on it and make corners as x=i*sz, y=j*sz, z=0; Note that this is local coordinate system linked to CB, not camera center.

Comment: Alb, my bad, the PnP is not Least Squares but min direction problem and to avoid the trivial solution it is solved with constraint |x|=1; to solve it one uses SVD (singular value decomposition) of A and pick up the last column of V (it corresponds to the smallest axis of covariance ellipse of A or smallest singular value). I updated my answer, see above.

Comment: Hi Vlad, thanks for your input. Do you know where I can find something more detailed and formal about the procedure you have described? I'd like to implement this and write some documentation, so I want to have a clear idea of what I'm doing. Also, I don't understand what the R2 matrix is. If I calculate SVD from the overdetermined system, then U is mxm and V is  nxn dimension , so what do you mean by R2 = UV' ?

Comment: Hi Alb, Rotation matrices are square so m=n; the whole point of SVD is ensure that rotation is not contaminated by scaling. Formally a good book to read is Computer Vision by Simon Prince. It is available in hardcover as well as online with a nice booklet of practical algorithm implementations (pseudo code): http://www.computervisionmodels.com look at chapters 15, 16 for single and stereo cameras, chapter 14 describes image processing. The appendix is really concise and useful for understanding optimization and matrix ops

Comment: Yes, I didn't get that you have to apply SVD again ,this time on your rotation matrix. But reading the book you mentioned it's perfectly clear.

Comment: Sorry, English is not my first language. Simon Prince is a great writer. Sometimes he explains something in one page while it takes a chapter for Hartley and Zisserman to describe (though they do this in great detail but so painfully!)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by "calibrated" you mean that you have a pinhole model for your camera.

Then the transformation between your chessboard plane and the image plane is a homography, which you can estimate from the image of the corners using the usual DLT algorithm. You can then express it as the product, up to scale, of the matrix of intrinsic parameters A and [x  y t], where x and y columns are the x and y unit vectors of the world's (i.e. chessboard's) coordinate frame, and t is the vector from the camera centre to the origin of that same frame. That is:

H = scale * A * [x|y|t]

Therefore

[x|y|t] = 1/scale * inv(A) * H

The scale is chosen so that x and y have unit length. Once you have x and y, the third axis is just their cross product.